# How to visualize a multiline graphic in R?

Tags: r, graphics, datavisualization.toolkit

I have the folloing  R code which visualizes a multiline graph where each line corresponds to a category of data. In the code the categories are given my the variable nk:
My dataset looks like this :

```
k   precision   recall
0.25    0.02    1.011
0.25    0.04    1.011
0.5 0.15    0.941
0.5 0.17    0.931
0.5 0.18    0.921
0.5 0.19    0.911
1.0 0.36    0.831
1.0 0.39    0.811
1.0 0.41    0.801
```

The problem is that it only visualizes the lines for k = 1.0 and not the lines for k = 0.5 and 0.25
My question is ? How can i use a nk variable which is not
an integer in order to visualize lines for k = 0.5 or 0.25?

```
dtf$k <- as.numeric(dtf$k)
nk <- max(dtf$k)
xrange <- range(dtf$precision)
yrange <- range(dtf$recall)
plot(xrange, yrange,
 type="n",
 xlab="Precision",
 ylab="Recall"
 )
colors <- rainbow(nk)
linetype <- c(1:nk)
plotchar <- seq(18, 18+nk, 1)
for (i in 1:nk) {
 Ki <- subset(dtf, k==i)
 lines(Ki$precision, Ki$recall,
 type="b",
 lwd=2,
 lty=linetype[i],
 col=colors[i],
 pch=plotchar[i]
 )
}
title("Methods varying K", "Precision Recall")
legend(xrange[1], yrange[2],
 1:nk,
 cex=1.0,
 col=colors,
inset=c(-0.2,0),
 pch=plotchar,
 lty=linetype,
 title="k"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Data

```
    dtf <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'k   precision   recall
0.25    0.02    1.011
0.25    0.04    1.011
0.5 0.15    0.941
0.5 0.17    0.931
0.5 0.18    0.921
0.5 0.19    0.911
1.0 0.36    0.831
1.0 0.39    0.811
1.0 0.41    0.801')
dtf$k <- factor(dtf$k)
```

## ggplot2 solution

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dtf, aes(x = precision, y = recall, col = k)) +
  geom_line()
```

## base solution

```
plot(recall ~ precision, data = dtf, type = 'n')
cols = c('red', 'blue', 'green')
levs <- levels(df$k)
for(i in seq_along(levs)){
  take <- df[df$k == levs[i], ]
  lines(take$precision, take$recall, col = cols[i])
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but It gives me an error when i call ggplot function to design the line. The error is this one : 
Errore in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq((function (i)  : 
  oggetto ".rcpp_warning_recorder" non trovato

Comment: With my example data?! Or with your actual data?